# When transferring an android app to to another Google Play account, what happens to the certificate?

Tags: android, google-play, certificate

It isn't unusual for a company to sign all of its apps with the same certificate.

What happens if the company (say Company A)  wants to transfer control of the app to another company (Company B)? The problem is that if Company A has signed other apps with the same certificate, it doesn't make sense to give the certificate to company B.

So what does one do in this case ?

Comment: You can enroll to new Google App Signing and then request for new upload key https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en nothing can be done for existing apps

Comment: @AmodGokhale But is it possible to use a different certificate for each app ? That way if you transfer an app to another company you can give that company the certificate just for that app ?

Comment: yes its possible but if you create separate certificate for each app from start, in above case now you cannot change unless you enroll to new Google App Signing and change upload key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Company A gives the certificate to Company B. There will be no issues with the app and the updates, but it might not be practical for one Company to give its signing certificate to other company.

Option 2: Company B signs the app with a new certificate, with a new package name. But now that will result in a new app in the Google Play store, not as an update to the old app. One time hiccup to all the users.

Option 3: Company B should depend on Company A to sign the app for further future releases. But this might not be practical either.

Comment: But is it possible to use a different certificate for each app ? That way if you transfer an app to another company you can give that company the certificate just for that app ?

Comment: Yes. That is possible. But you would lose signature protectionLevel level features available. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

Comment: But why would one lost signature protectionLevel features ? Since the certificate is the same, and we have just transferred the certificate to someone else, shouldn't the feature still work ?

Comment: I meant we get some permission features if multiple apps are signed with the same certificate, probably all the apps of a company. If you are going to use a different certificate for different apps, then you won't get that feature.